# Generation of multidimensional Grid in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a N dimensional array of points that represents the sampling of a function. Then I am using the numpy histogramdd to create a multi dimensional histogram :

```
histoComp,edges = np.histogramdd(pointsFunction,bins =  [np.unique(pointsFunction[:,i]) for i in range(dim)])
```

Next I am trying to generate a "grid" with the coordinate of the different points of each bin.
To do so, I am using :

```
Grid = np.vstack(np.meshgrid([edges[i] for i in range(len(edges))])).reshape(len(edges),-1).T
```

However this doesn't work the way I expected it to because the input of np.meshgrid is a list of arrays instead of arrays... But I have to use a generator given that the number of edges is not known.

Any tips ?

---UPDATE---
Here is an example of what I mean by "not working"

```
>>>a = [4, 8, 7, 5, 9]
>>>b = [7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

So this is the kind of result I want :

```
>>>np.vstack(np.meshgrid(a,b)).reshape(2,-1).T
array([[4, 7],
   [8, 7],
   [7, 7],
   [5, 7],
   [9, 7],
   [4, 8],
   [8, 8],
   [7, 8],
   [5, 8],
   [9, 8],
   [4, 9],
   [8, 9],
   [7, 9],
   [5, 9],
   [9, 9],
   [4, 4],
   [8, 4],
   [7, 4],
   [5, 4],
   [9, 4],
   [4, 5],
   [8, 5],
   [7, 5],
   [5, 5],
   [9, 5]])
```

But this is the result I get :

```
>>> np.vstack(np.meshgrid([a,b])).reshape(2,-1).T
array([[4, 7],
   [8, 8],
   [7, 9],
   [5, 4],
   [9, 5]])
```

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: I mean I do not have the expected grid that I can get if I input arrays instead of a list of array. I will update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`*` argument unpacking operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/):

```
np.meshgrid(*[A, B, C])
```

is equivalent to

```
np.meshgrid(A, B, C)
```

Since `edges` is a list, `np.meshgrid(*edges)` unpacks the items in `edges` and passes them as arguments to `np.meshgrid`.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 0, 1])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1])
z = np.array([0, 0, 3])
xedges = np.linspace(0, 4, 3)
yedges = np.linspace(0, 4, 3)
zedges = np.linspace(0, 4, 3)
xyz = np.vstack((x, y, z)).T
hist, edges = np.histogramdd(xyz, (xedges, yedges, zedges))
grid = np.vstack(np.meshgrid(*edges)).reshape(len(edges), -1).T
```

yields

```
In [153]: grid
Out[153]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  4.],
       ...
       [ 2.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.]])
```